How to get file from "file_picker" to upload in flutter web?
I need to upload a PDF file to the server.
I use this code.
  void pickFiles() async {
    try {
      final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        allowMultiple: false,
        type: FileType.custom,
        withData: true,
        allowedExtensions: ['pdf'],
      );

      Uint8List? fileBytes = result!.files.first.bytes;
      base64String = base64Encode(fileBytes!);
      nameDocumentController.text = result.files.first.name;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Unsupported operation$e');
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }

I don't understand why this code doesn't work. On the server I find the file but with 0 bytes
I tried all the examples online but in the end base64String is always empty.
Where can I find a working example?
Thanks
Biagio

Let me show you the code I use to upload a file in PDF format to Firebase.
These are the necessary variables.
  Uint8List? fileBytes;
  String fileUploadName = "";

I am using the selectFile function to pick a PDF file with a maximum size of 50 MB.
Future selectFile() async {
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        type: FileType.custom,
        allowedExtensions: ['pdf'],
        allowMultiple: false);

    if (result == null) {
      return;
    } else {
      final file = result.files.first;
      const maxSize = 50 * 1024 * 1024;
      if (file.size > maxSize) {
        fileSizeErrorDialog();
        return;
      }
      if (file.extension != 'pdf') {
        showPdfFormatErrorDialog();
        return;
      }

      fileBytes = file.bytes;
      fileUploadName = file.name;
    }
  }

I use the uploadFile function to upload it to Firebase. The fileBytes variable is important here as it holds the file data.
Future uploadFile(
  Uint8List? fileBytes,
  String fileUploadName,
  String uuid, {
  bool isAnnouncement = false,
}) async {
  try {
    if (fileBytes == null) {
      throw 'didntSelectFile'.tr;
    }
    if (isAnnouncement) {
      await firebaseStorage
          .ref('announcement/$uuid/$fileUploadName')
          .putData(fileBytes);
      return;
    }
    await firebaseStorage.ref('uploads/$uuid/$fileUploadName').putData(fileBytes);
  } catch (e) {
    throw '${'errorUploadingFile'.tr} : $e';
  }
}

I hope this example helps.
